# How can I create readonly user for backups in PostgreSQL?

Tags: backup, postgresql-9.1, permissions

Is it true that it is IMPOSSIBLE to create a readonly backup user in PostgreSQL?

I've been advised on an IRC channel that you simply can't have a backup only user with no ownership privileges.  I find it very strange so I want to make sure I'm not missing something.

Below is what I tried but it doesn't give me the results I'm looking for.  When I do `pg_dump` on a given table I'm getting `Permission denied for relation...`:

```
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO backup; 
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO backup; 
GRANT SELECT, USAGE ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO backup;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT, USAGE ON SEQUENCES TO backup;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: [Modern way to do this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/160817/2639)

Answer (score 22):

No, it's easy (now anyway).

1. Grant the connect permission on a new user

   ```
   GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE mydb TO myReadolyUser;
   ```
2. Grant the permissions on all the *current* database objects. This is schema-specific, and you'll have to run one copy for every schema you wish for your user to use,

   ```
   GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA mySchema TO myReadonlyUser;
   ```

   From [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-grant.html), `ALL TABLES` includes everything you'd want.

   > There is also an option to grant privileges on all objects of the same type within one or more schemas. This functionality is currently supported only for tables, sequences, and functions (but note that **ALL TABLES is considered to include views and foreign tables.**
3. Then [`ALTER DEFAULT PRIVLEGES`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-grant.html) to grant *future* `SELECT` privileges for objects not yet created.

   ```
   ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA mySchema
   GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO myReadonlyUser;
   ```

Comment: I noticed that when running `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES ... myReadonlyUser`, 2 additional lines are added to the dump: `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE root IN SCHEMA public REVOKE ALL ON TABLES FROM PUBLIC; ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE root IN SCHEMA public REVOKE ALL ON TABLES FROM root;`. Sounds like this will mean root won't be able to do anything on new tables. Is this true?

Comment: Also, if your tables use `bigint` your readonly user will likely also need `GRANT SELECT ON ALL SEQUENCES`

Answer (score 9):

The simple and nice way is to create a superuser with read only permission.

- Login `psql` as postgres or other superuser.
- Create the new superuser role and set it to read only :

  ```
  CREATE USER backadm SUPERUSER  password '<PASS>';
  ALTER USER backadm set default_transaction_read_only = on;
  ```

  - Replace `<PASS>` by your choosen password.
  - You can replace `backadm` by the choosen username. (I put `backadm` for `Backup Administrator`).
  - Do NOT forgot the single quotes for the password.

You can now use this role to backup.

Comment: Ewww. A superuser to backup? He specifically asked for read only. That user is one `SET SESSION CHARACTERISTICS AS TRANSACTION READ WRITE` or `ALTER USER backadm set default_transaction_read_only = off;` away from having unrestricted access to the database.

Comment: This user will still able to drop tables/schemas/databases regardless of that the transactions are read only.

Comment: Why would you grant such elevated rights for a backup user?

Comment: To be fair, a lot of backup software uses the postgres user by default... there isn't really a good solution.

Answer (score 7):

After testing back up with Evan Caroll's solution 
I came across this error:

> ERROR: permission denied for relation 'table'

there's one other permission missing:

```
GRANT SELECT ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA mySchema TO myReadonlyUser
```

Adding this permission enabled me to do back up with my read-only user.

Answer (score 6):

Note the blog referenced in the [answer given by @Gyre](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/52706/10832) will not work for creating an "application" read-only user (i.e, for creating a read only role for a web application to connect to the database), and might open up a serious security vulnerability, since its easily circumventable, as explained [in this postgresql list response](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/bddc86151003030706l1a50b54as9d07f7f5c748b535@mail.gmail.com). For reference, by the client overriding the session settings:

```
SET SESSION CHARACTERISTICS AS TRANSACTION READ WRITE
```

Refer ['Managing rights in postgresql' presentation linked in the postgres wiki](http://wiki.postgresql.org/images/d/d1/Managing_rights_in_postgresql.pdf) for a more detailed method, similar to the one posted in the question.

Comment: This is not really an answer, it's a critique on the other answers for being insecure which I've copied as a comment. I've answered this question properly now.

Answer (score 5):

If you want (or can live with) a backup user having read-only access **to all databases**, you may use the [`pg_read_all_data` role](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/E1lTTHk-0006rH-HD%40gemulon.postgresql.org) since the release of Postgres 14.

You can create such new user with permissions to read everything by running:

```
CREATE ROLE backup WITH ROLE pg_read_all_data LOGIN PASSWORD '<password>';
```

Comment: in order to use `pg_basebackup` I needed to also add `REPLICATION` role

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not worked for me until I executed 2 operations: `CREATE USER dbuser;` and `GRANT pg_read_all_data TO dbuser;`

Comment: Found out you need to use `CREATE ROLE backup WITH IN ROLE pg_read_all_data LOGIN PASSWORD '<password>` and if you are using the `postgres` database you need to specify the database `pg_dump postgres://backup:<password>@<database_uri>/postgres > dump.sql`

Answer (score 3):

I have done some proper research and there DOES seem to be a solution for this. I've come across this [blog post](http://vibhorkumar.wordpress.com/2012/03/) which perfectly explains what needs to be done. I hope this helps to people who are looking for the same answer as I was. Obviously - restoring the backups done this way is a different question.

Comment: Instead of simply linking to the blog post, you should add some details to your answer in case the blog post suffers from link-rot (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot )

Comment: The basic idea from the blogpost is `ALTER USER  set default_transaction_read_only = on;`, which does not prevent the user from changing it.

Comment: Ewww. A superuser to backup? He specifically asked for read only. That user is one SET SESSION CHARACTERISTICS AS TRANSACTION READ WRITE or ALTER USER backadm set default_transaction_read_only = off; away from having unrestricted access to the database.